# Algorithm for unique objects from an array with sub-objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a data class:

```
@interface Car : NSObject
{
  Engine *_engine;
}
//...
```

With the class:

```
@interface Engine : NSObject
{
  NSInteger _power;
  NSString *_name;
}
//...
```

And an array:

```
NSArray *myArray = [ // a bunch of Car objects with Engines
```

How would I make a new array that contains all unique items based on Engine 'power'?

For Example:

0 Car with Engine ( power = 20, name = "engine one" )

1 Car with Engine ( power = 45, name = "engine two" )

2 Car with Engine ( power = 20, name = "engine three" )

Final array would be car objects 0 and 1

Both data classes have accessors, e.g:

```
- (NSInteger)power;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *cars = ...;
NSMutableDictionary *carsByUniqueEnginePowers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (Car *car in cars) {
    NSNumber *enginePower = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:car.engine.power];
    [carsByUniqueEnginePowers setObject:car forKey:enginePower];
}
NSArray *carsWithUniqueEnginePowers = [carsByUniqueEnginePowers allValues];
```

Will pick the last item per engine power.

To get the first one replace the line

```
[carsByUniqueEnginePowers setObject:car forKey:enginePower];
```

with this:

```
if (![carsByUniqueEnginePowers objectForKey:power]) {
    [carsByUniqueEnginePowers setObject:car forKey:enginePower];
}
```

Comment: Try it in a moment...order doesn't really matter as long as it's unique

Comment: @Javy: Updated answer to cover "first occurences".

Comment: This seems to sort through an engine array, but I have an array of car objects that have engine objects with a power property...so this would only sort an array of engine objects, correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread your question then. Updated answer. Should fit your needs now.

Comment: Yeah, perfect...I'm definitely going to look into those methods some more.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Well, it's certainly no magic going on here. You're basically just "abusing" the uniqueness property of dictionary keys for the sake of unique-ing your array by a given key path. There cannot be two objects with the same key in a dictionary. And as we're using the engine power as key you're essentially filtering out all duplicates. Eventually calling `allKeys` on the dict returns a nicely filtered array of cars. Hope that clears it up a bit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the array, building up a list of indices whose objects have previously-unseen `power` values.

Create a set to hold the already-seen `power`s; [`-[NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW24) handles building the index list. Then ask the original array for its [`objectsAtIndexes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJGGAAA).

```
NSMutableSet * powerSet = [NSMutableSet set];
NSIndexSet * indexes;
indexes = [carArr indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id car, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                  // valueForKey: will return an NSNumber instance for scalar values.        
                  NSNumber * powerNum = [[car engine] valueForKey:@"power"];
                  // This power is already in the set; pass over this car.
                  if( [powerSet containsObject:powerNum] ){
                      return NO;
                  }
                  // Add the new power to the set and include this car in the index set.        
                  else {
                      [powerSet addObject:powerNum];
                      return YES;
                  }
              }];
NSArray * uniqueEnginePowerCars = [carArr objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but Regexident's code was what I used.  Thanks for the help.